# Can't resolve error :The package installation failed because a version of the service exists outside of APPX packaging

Tags: powershell, installation, windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl2

I tried installing WSL after it crashed and I keep running into Error: 0x80073D27.

I use a Windows 11 (x64 Windows 11 Home Build: 22621.1485) system and had a windows subsystem for linux (WSL2) installed. I used an Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS. After an update, the WSL completely stopped responding and I lost all my data and decided to reinstall everything. When I try to install WSL off of the Microsoft store I keep getting this error:

[image: Error code: 0x80073D27]

I tried installing again using powershell and keep running into this error:

Installing: Windows Subsystem for Linux The package installation failed because a version of the service exists outside of APPX packaging. Please contact your software vendor.

I have tried all the solutions I could find online to no avail. This website shows most of the solution I have attempted: https://www.appdeploynews.com/packaging-types/msix-errors/msix-error-code-0x80073d27/

This is also a website that is meant for troubleshooting these errors: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/appxpkg/troubleshooting

If anyone has any suggestions I would be glad to try them out.

Comment: [Edit] your question to include the version and the edition of Windows 10 (or Windows 11) you are using. I assume you uninstall the optional features and then simply ran `wsl --install` without success?

Comment: Did you try the suggestions I gave when you posted this to U&L?

Comment: @Ramhound. When I deleted all optional features and attempted `wsl --install` I got this reply Windows Subsystem for Linux is already installed.  ```The following is a list of valid distributions that can be installed. Install using 'wsl --install -d Distro'.```  followed by a list of distros that I can install. I tried uninstalling WSL but all the methods suggested to remove it directly from the Windows task manager. Is there a way to directly uninstall it via Powershell

Comment: @Peregrino69. 
With respect to "After an update...". I tried running WSL as I normally would but didn't run as it normally would. I can't recall what the error was but Ubuntu kept saying click enter to close Ubuntu. The internet suggested to update WSL. From then onwards I keep getting the same error message: "Installing: Windows Subsystem for Linux The package installation failed because... "
I ran DISM and it returned that the ImageHealthState was healthy. 
`sfc /scannow` also says it didn't find any integritiy violations.